# Display DIV one after another using HTML/JQuery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Live Demo: [**Live Demo**](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/testFolder/input.htm)

HTML:

```
   <div class="target">
      <img src="bg-clock.png" alt="jQuery" />
   </div>
   <div class="target2">
      <img src="bg-clock.png" alt="jQuery" />
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.target, .target2 {
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".target").show( "drop", 
                      {direction: "down"}, 1000 );
       $(".target2").show( "drop", 
                      {direction: "down"}, 1000 );

  });
```

Right now both DIV appear at the same time but I want `target2` to appear after `target1` has completed it's animation and so forth for any other DIV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `complete` callback of the first animation function: So that `target2` is animated only once the `target1`'s animation is completed.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".target").show("drop", {
          direction: "down",
          complete: function () {
              $(".target2").show("drop", {
                  direction: "down"
              }, 1000);

          }
      }, 1000);

  });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QL9DF/)**

**[.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-options)**

For a series of targets you can do this way:

Just provide a common class name called `slideIn` for your targets for collecting them using a single selector. You can also use multiple classnames in the selector or attribute startswith selector

```
  var elems = $('.slideIn').get(); // get all the targets to an array.

  function animate() {
      var elem = elems.shift(); //remove the top element from the array

      $(elem).show("drop", { //animate it
          direction: "down",
          complete: function () {
             if(elems.length > 0)
                window.setTimeout(animate); //use recursive callback
          }
      }, 1000);
  }

  animate(); //invoke for the first time.
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DNsNC/)**

Comment: So if I have four target, I would nest in within each?

Comment: Any difference between `$('.slideIn').get()` and `$('.slideIn')`?

Comment: @Jonathan yup there is a difference. former will get you the array of DOM elements where you can apply array operation like shift() latter will get you the collection object.

Comment: I went with your original script. Thanks! the second one is not working for me for some reason

Comment: @SiKni8 Any idea why any errors? Did you add the class in the markup?

Comment: @PSL Can you tell me why the four header navigation in this page (http://www.interfaithmedical.com/pz/index.htm) is not doing the same thing as this page (http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/testFolder/input.htm)? I implemented everything the same way

Comment: The second one worked as well... I might have missed something.

Comment: @SiKni8 seems like you have css specificity issue. See without the script it shows all of them. It should n't ideally. slide will not work if it is not display:none. Please remember to mark as answer if your question got the answer that you are looking for.. :)

Comment: I figured out how to fix it. But in IE it comes out on top of each other. Can you please check one more time and tell me why they aren't coming the same way in IE.

Comment: @SiKni8 which version 9 looks fine. If any other version instead of using display:inline-block try use `float:left`

Comment: IE8 But I will try your method now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have many targets I would not use a callback. The nesting would get nasty.
You could use a delay on each

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".target").show( "drop", 
                  {direction: "down"}, 1000 );
     $(".target2").delay(200).show( "drop", 
                  {direction: "down"}, 1000 );
     $(".target3").delay(200).show( "drop", 
                  {direction: "down"}, 1000 );
     $(".target4").delay(200).show( "drop", 
                  {direction: "down"}, 1000 );
```

});

This will have a slight pause between each you can play with the time to achive your effect